# SearchView - Show starting of the text when suggestion is selected and set

Tags: android, searchview

I guess it must be simple but can't figure it out myself.

I have a searchview in my app which on typing gives out some suggestions. On selection(tap) of a particular suggestion from the list dropped down, the suggestion text is set into the searchview, but the focus/cursor is at the end of the text. Image below you can see the cursor is at the end.[image]

Is there anyway to set the cursor to the start of the text in searchview? So that when a text is set, the starting of the text is displayed and not the end part.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please attach screenshot so that i can help you

Comment: @jiteshmohite - Added a screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Actually searchView uses textview as edittext where we set query. An EditText is a TextView, it inherits TextView. So first of all find id of that textview as below.

```
TextView searchText = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```

or use this method

```
int id = searchView.getContext()
               .getResources() 
               .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null); 
         EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(id);
```

2 - Now use this edittext to search your data.

3 - After getting result of your query you can use editText.setSelection(0) method to set focus/cursor on 0 position....

It works for me, hope this will help you too....

Comment: How do I find the id of the textView? If I am not wrong you are saying that Searchview is a child of textView ? I tried setSelection(0) but no such method for SearchView

Comment: I guess the first option looks better? Let me try this and get back to you. Thanks :)